# How to add animation to this javascript show/hide function?

Tags: javascript, gridview, show-hide

I am using  Javascript to show/hide a nested gridview (to show some details)  inside a main gridview like so:

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   DataKeyNames="ResID" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" > 
        <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("ResID") %>', 'one');">Details</a>
                  </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>            

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"  HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact"  HeaderText="Contact" SortExpression="Contact" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Response" HeaderText="Response" SortExpression="Response"/>
                      <asp:TemplateField>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                       </td></tr>  
                                           <tr>    
                                              <td colspan="100%" style="padding-left: 25px;padding-top: 5px" >                     

                                     <div id="div<%# Eval("ResID") %>" style="display:none;  left: 30px;" >
                                           <!--nested Grid:-->
                                                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"   AutoGenerateColumns="false"  DataKeyNames="ResID" >
                                                     <Columns>
                                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="iDate" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" HeaderText="iDate" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"/>
                                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="iContact"  HeaderText="Contact" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
                                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="iComments" HeaderText="Comments"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
                                                  </Columns>
                                                 </asp:GridView>
                                               <p></p>
                                 </div>

                                     </td>
                                     </tr>                    
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
```

and the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function switchViews(obj, row) {

var div = document.getElementById(obj);

if (div.style.display == "none")
     {
         div.style.display = "inline";

     }
     else
      {
         div.style.display = "none";
      }
 }
</script>
```

So, this works fine, but what code is needed to add animation to the show/hide for smoother effect?  Thank You!

Comment: Yeah, but don't know enough about it to convert the current script to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your friend: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

basically (with jQuery installed) you'd do something like:

```
function switchViews(obj, row) {
    var div = $('#'+obj),
        targetOpacity = div.css('opacity') === '1' ? 0 : 1,
        startOpacity = +!targetOpacity;
    div
    .stop()
    .css('opacity', startOpacity)
    .animate({opacity: targetOpacity}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just swapped my code for yours. But on click: nothing. I've used jquery just a little, and am not following your example very well. Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that your 'obj' parameter was an ID.  jQuery ID selectors must be prepended with '#' - this should be fixed now.

Comment: Hmm. Still nothing happening when clicking when trying your latest revision. Look forward to anything else you think may work. Thank you!

Comment: @Doug - are you sure you're doing everything correctly?  When I run that method in firebug on stackoverflow.com and then run switchViews('hlogo'), the stackoverflow logo fades out.  Running it again causes the logo to reappear.

Comment: OK: Working :)  However the show/hide is really fast - like it was with my original script. Can I assume that I need to change the 1000 value to something less for it to show/hide slower? Thanks again DigitalBath...

Comment: Yes, 1000 is the animation duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've added 2 classes to your table, since it's easier to apply the client side code to all the elements at one time based on a class name.

Here is the JavaScript / jQuery Code to Hide/Show the Div and Change the text from "Show Details" to "Hide Details".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showDetails').click(function () {
            // Show Details DIV
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').toggle('fast');
            // Return false to disable default postback on click of a <a> element
            return false;
        }).toggle(
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when hiding.
                $(this).html('Hide Details').stop();
            },
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when showing.
                $(this).html('Show Details').stop();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Here is your modified GridView with the classes added.  It doesn't seem like anything is being done with the ID on the /, so you could remove those if they are not needed for something else.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ResID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a class="showDetails" href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("ResID") %>', 'one');">Show Details</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" SortExpression="Contact" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Response" HeaderText="Response" SortExpression="Response" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                </td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 5px">
                        <div class="details" id="div<%# Eval("ResID") %>" style="display: none; left: 30px;">
                            <!--nested Grid:-->
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ResID">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="iDate" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" HeaderText="iDate" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="iContact" HeaderText="Contact" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="iComments" HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <p>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Hi Zach... when trying your changes, the only thing that happens is the link text changes from 'Show Details' to 'Hide Details' - but the div containing the nested grid never shows (or hides)... Thanks for trying. Any other ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: I tested it and it worked for me, it pops up the div inside of the 'td' element.  I did test with a rendered nested table structure since I can't bind your data sources.  Did you check firebug console, did you have any errors ?

Comment: Firebug: No errors, warnings in the console. Just blank. The only part of your script that's not working is here:  $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').toggle('fast');

Comment: If I change that line to  $(this).closest('div').find('.details').toggle('fast'); - then the page does respond with ALL nested grids showing/hiding when only any single link is clicked. Close, but not quite... Thank you Zach.